# Really slow Git clone command

Tags: ubuntu, git, github

I tried to clone using the following command: `git clone http://github.com/WinPack/boulder.git` and it had speeds of 10KB/s!!!!! Why is this? How can I correct that? I should have 100 times more speed than that!

My normal speed is 6 MB/s (MegaByte, not MegaBit), VDSL Connection. This speed is as expected on browsers. I have an Intel i7 CPU and 8GB RAM. I am running Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again, if still an issue something is wrong with your computer/local network/WAN connection given my test below.  Note other programs and users on the local network may be using the internet as well limiting your available bandwidth.  Consider trying a speed test www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/

ISP Internet Speed is typically referenced in MB/s Megabits/second.  6 Mb/s =>  0.750 MB/s 
[standard VDSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-high-bit-rate_digital_subscriber_line) v1 max of 55 Mb/s.

```
git clone http://github.com/WinPack/boulder.git
 Cloning into 'boulder'...
 remote: Counting objects: 12349, done.
 remote: Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
 remote: Total 12349 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 12319
 Receiving objects: 100% (12349/12349), 12.64 MiB | 1.66 MiB/s, done.
 Resolving deltas: 100% (7602/7602), done.
 Checking connectivity... done.
```

[Cable Modem 15Mb/s]

Try [Diagnosing Git HUB Slowness](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow)

Comment: Nope, our ISP has VDSL with 50 MBPS. I have almost 43 Mb/s.

Comment: The speed test now displays 41Mb/s. Still git clone with 12KiB/s...

Comment: Do you see the compression I show?  Without that speed may be orders of magnitute slower.

Comment: OK, still I am entitled to more git speed. How can I do that? Maybe I did something wrong with my SSH keys?

Comment: Please post the output of your Git clone command with the diagnostics mentioned in the Diagnosing link.  Also may be worth trying a quick VM on your box with completly stock setup to test if it might be your configeration.

Comment: OK, I will now go crazy. After restarting my modem/router, so that a new IP address is obtained, different from the old one, everything is back to normal!!! (And after running most of the 'diagnosing' commands above) So, nothing more is required! I just had to restart my modem... So simple..... Anyway, thanks for your help!